# php parse string with comma and quotes

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, quotes

I am trying to parse the following string into an array.

```
$str = [0,"Victoria Station, Bus Station Stand",null,null,0,null,51.496169,-0.143633]
```

I am using

```
$result = explode(',', $str);
```

and am getting an array like this

```
Array ( [0] => [0 [1] => "Victoria Station [2] => Bus Station Stand" [3] => null [4] => null [5] => 0 [6] => null [7] => 51.496169 [8] => -0.143633] )
```

But I need "Victoria Station, Bus Station Stand" to be 1 item in the array. I understand that this could be achieved with regular expressions. But I am new to that. Your guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like `json` to me try

```
$str = '[0,"Victoria Station, Bus Station Stand",null,null,0,null,51.496169,-0.143633]';
$json = json_decode($str, true);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($json);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => int 0
  1 => string 'Victoria Station, Bus Station Stand' (length=35)
  2 => null
  3 => null
  4 => int 0
  5 => null
  6 => float 51.496169
  7 => float -0.143633
```

Comment: Better use `var_dump` or `var_export` instead of `print_r`.

Comment: @Baba Thanks a ton! It works like a charm! Much better than the regex approach I was taking earlier. And you folks are blazingly fast!